# MUI Paper keep reRendering

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So I a trying to build fitness app which have a timer. I am using MUI. But I notice something that breaks my app. Whenever I use the Paper components or Item which is a Papaer based one it keep reloading or rerendering. So If I wrap my app in Paper to give it a better look and I try to enter a value into the TextArea I can't get it to focus it loses focus since it is reloading.

```
import { React, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button, Fab } from "@mui/material";
import Dialog from "@mui/material/Dialog";
import DialogActions from "@mui/material/DialogActions";
import DialogContent from "@mui/material/DialogContent";
import DialogContentText from "@mui/material/DialogContentText";
import DialogTitle from "@mui/material/DialogTitle";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import PauseIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Pause";
import PlayIcon from "@mui/icons-material/PlayArrow";

import StopIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Stop";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import { experimentalStyled as styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import RestartAltIcon from "@mui/icons-material/RestartAlt";
import ListItem from "@mui/material/ListItem";
import ListItemButton from "@mui/material/ListItemButton";
import ListItemText from "@mui/material/ListItemText";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import AddIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Add";
import List from "@mui/material/List";
import { CardHeader } from "@mui/material";

function createData(id, dayNum, dayName, exercises) {
  return { id, dayNum, dayName, exercises };
}
const rows = createData(1, 1, "Shoulders", {
  "Rear Delt Fly": [15, 15, 15, 15],
  "High Incline Lateral Raise": [12, 10, 8, 8],
  "Seated Dumbbell Press": [15, 15, 15, 15],
  "Single-Arm Kettlebell Press": [12, 10, 8, 8],
});

function WorkoutProgress(props) {
  const { index, style } = props;
  const [exerciseLogs, setExerciseLogs] = useState(null);
  const [reps, setReps] = useState("");
  const [kg, setKg] = useState("");
  const [curr, setCurr] = useState(0);
  // state to store time
  const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
  // state to check stopwatch running or not
  const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = useState(true);
  const params = useParams();
  const id = params.dayID;
  const [warning, setWarning] = useState(false);
  const Item = styled(Paper)(({ theme }) => ({
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === "dark" ? "#1A2027" : "#fff",
    ...theme.typography.body2,
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    borderRadius: "22px",

    textAlign: "center",
    boxShadow:
      "rgba(145, 158, 171, 0.2) 0px 0px 2px 0px, rgba(145, 158, 171, 0.12) 0px 12px 24px -4px",

    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  }));
  useEffect(() => {
    let intervalId = null;
    if (isRunning) {
      // setting time from 0 to 1 every 10 milisecond using javascript setInterval method
      intervalId = setInterval(() => setTime((time) => time + 1), 10);
    } else {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, [isRunning]);
  // Hours calculation
  const hours = Math.floor(time / 360000);

  // Minutes calculation
  const minutes = Math.floor((time % 360000) / 6000);

  // Seconds calculation
  const seconds = Math.floor((time % 6000) / 100);

  // Milliseconds calculation
  const milliseconds = time % 100;

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignContent: "center",
          marginBottom: "30px",
        }}
      >
        <Item
          sx={{
            background: "#d40000",
            borderRadius: "202px",
            width: "20rem",
            color: "#fff",
          }}
        >
          <CardHeader
            sx={{ textAlign: "center", padding: "0" }}
            title={Object.keys(rows.exercises)[curr]}
            titleTypographyProps={{ fontSize: "18px" }}
          />
        </Item>
      </div>

      <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-evenly" }}>
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "column",
            height: "200px",
            justifyContent: "space-between",
          }}
        >
          <div>
            <Button
              color="primary"
              aria-label="add"
              sx={{
                minWidth: "auto !important",
                outline: "#d40000 solid 1px",
                borderRadius: "220px",
                padding: "0px",
              }}
            >
              <div
                style={{
                  height: "74px",
                  width: "74px",
                  display: "flex",
                  alignItems: "center",
                  justifyContent: "center",
                }}
              >
                <RestartAltIcon />
              </div>
            </Button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <Button
              color="primary"
              aria-label="add"
              sx={{
                minWidth: "auto !important",
                outline: "#d40000 solid 1px",
                borderRadius: "220px",
                padding: "0px",
              }}
            >
              <div
                style={{
                  height: "74px",
                  width: "74px",
                  display: "flex",
                  alignItems: "center",
                  justifyContent: "center",
                }}
              >
                Auto
              </div>
            </Button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            alignItems: "center",
          }}
        >
          <Item
            sx={{
              background: "#d40000",
              width: "120px",
              height: "120px",
              display: "flex",
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center",
              color: "#fff",
              borderRadius: "50%",
            }}
          >
            <div>
              <h3
                style={{
                  fontWeight: "300",
                  fontSize: "1.5rem",
                }}
              >
                {hours.toString().padStart(2, "0")}:
                {minutes.toString().padStart(2, "0")}:
                {seconds.toString().padStart(2, "0")}:
                {milliseconds.toString().padStart(2, "0")}
              </h3>
            </div>
          </Item>
        </div>
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "column",
            height: "200px",
            justifyContent: "space-between",
          }}
        >
          <div>
            {" "}
            <Button
              color="primary"
              aria-label="add"
              sx={{
                minWidth: "auto !important",
                outline: "#d40000 solid 1px",
                borderRadius: "220px",
                padding: "0px",
              }}
            >
              <div
                style={{
                  height: "74px",
                  width: "74px",
                  display: "flex",
                  alignItems: "center",
                  justifyContent: "center",
                }}
              >
                Rest
              </div>
            </Button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <Button
              color="primary"
              aria-label="add"
              sx={{
                minWidth: "auto !important",
                outline: "#d40000 solid 1px",
                borderRadius: "220px",
                padding: "0px",
              }}
            >
              <div
                style={{
                  height: "74px",
                  width: "74px",
                  display: "flex",
                  alignItems: "center",
                  justifyContent: "center",
                }}
              >
                {rows.exercises[Object.keys(rows.exercises)[curr]].length -
                  2 +
                  " / " +
                  rows.exercises[Object.keys(rows.exercises)[curr]].length}
              </div>
            </Button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          marginTop: "40px",
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        <TextField
          id="outlined-basic"
          type="number"
          label="KG"
          value={kg}
          onChange={(event) => setKg(event.target.value)}
          variant="outlined"
          InputProps={{
            style: {
              borderRadius: "200px",
            },
          }}
          inputProps={{
            inputMode: "numeric",
          }}
          sx={{
            borderRadius: "20px",
            margin: "5px",
          }}
        />
        <TextField
          id="outlined-basic"
          type="number"
          label="Reps"
          value={reps}
          onChange={(event) => setReps(event.target.value)}
          variant="outlined"
          InputProps={{
            style: {
              borderRadius: "200px",
            },
          }}
          inputProps={{
            inputMode: "numeric",
          }}
          sx={{
            borderRadius: "20px",
            margin: "5px",
          }}
        />
        <Button
          color="primary"
          aria-label="add"
          sx={{
            minWidth: "auto !important",
            margin: "5px",
            outline: "#d40000 solid 1px",
            borderRadius: "220px",
            padding: "0px",
          }}
          onClick={() => {
            if (kg != "" && reps != "") {
              if (exerciseLogs == null) {
                setExerciseLogs([[kg, reps]]);
              } else {
                setExerciseLogs([[kg, reps], ...exerciseLogs]);
              }
            }
          }}
        >
          <div
            style={{
              height: "50px",
              width: "50px",
              display: "flex",
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center",
            }}
          >
            <AddIcon />
          </div>
        </Button>
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          marginTop: "20px",
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        <List style={{ maxHeight: "15vh", overflow: "auto", width: "30rem" }}>
          {exerciseLogs
            ? exerciseLogs.map((item, index) => {
                {
                  console.log(item);
                  console.log(index);
                }
                return (
                  <ListItem disablePadding>
                    <ListItemButton
                      onClick={() => {
                        setKg(item[0]);
                        setReps(item[1]);
                      }}
                    >
                      <ListItemText
                        key={index + "KG"}
                        primary={item[0] + " Kg"}
                      />
                      <ListItemText
                        key={index + "REPS"}
                        primary={item[1] + " Reps"}
                      />
                    </ListItemButton>
                  </ListItem>
                );
              })
            : null}
        </List>
      </div>
      <Fab
        color="primary"
        aria-label="Stop"
        onClick={() => setWarning(true)}
        sx={{
          height: "46px",
          width: "46px",
          boxShadow:
            "rgba(145, 158, 171, 0.2) 0px 0px 20px 0px, rgba(145, 158, 171, 0.12) 0px 12px 24px -4px",
          position: "fixed",
          bottom: 30,
          left: "3%",
          "@media (min-width: 820px)": {
            left: "3%",
          },
        }}
      >
        <StopIcon />
      </Fab>
      <Fab
        color="primary"
        variant="extended"
        onClick={() => {
          if (curr == Object.keys(rows).length - 1) {
            setWarning(true);
          } else {
            setCurr(curr + 1);
            setExerciseLogs(null);
            setKg("");
            setReps("");
          }
        }}
        sx={{
          height: "46px",
          boxShadow:
            "rgba(145, 158, 171, 0.2) 0px 0px 20px 0px, rgba(145, 158, 171, 0.12) 0px 12px 24px -4px",
          position: "fixed",
          bottom: 30,
          left: "30%",
          right: "30%",
          "@media (min-width: 820px)": {
            left: "40%",
            right: "40%",
          },
        }}
      >
        Next
      </Fab>
      <Fab
        color="primary"
        aria-label="add"
        onClick={() => setIsRunning(!isRunning)}
        sx={{
          height: "46px",
          width: "46px",
          boxShadow:
            "rgba(145, 158, 171, 0.2) 0px 0px 20px 0px, rgba(145, 158, 171, 0.12) 0px 12px 24px -4px",
          position: "fixed",
          bottom: 30,
          right: "3%",
          "@media (min-width: 820px)": {
            right: "3%",
          },
        }}
      >
        {isRunning ? <PauseIcon /> : <PlayIcon />}
      </Fab>
      <Dialog
        sx={{
          "& .MuiDialog-container": {
            "& .MuiPaper-root": {
              borderRadius: "22px",
              padding: "10px",
            },
          },
        }}
        open={warning}
        onClose={() => setWarning(false)}
        aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
      >
        <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">{"End Workout"}</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
            Are you sure you want to end your workout?
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Stack spacing={1.5} direction="row">
            <Button
              onClick={() => setWarning(false)}
              sx={{
                borderRadius: "200px",
              }}
              variant="outlined"
              disableElevation
            >
              Cancel
            </Button>
            <Link to={"/workout/"} style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
              <Button
                sx={{
                  borderRadius: "200px",
                }}
                variant="contained"
                disableElevation
              >
                END
              </Button>
            </Link>
          </Stack>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}

export default WorkoutProgress;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create component inside another component. The diffing algorithm thinks that its new component on each render. Move `Item` outside of `WorkoutProgress`

Item = styled(...)``

- This creates new function (component)
- then after state updates, rerender happens
- WorkoutProgress gets executed again (everything inside it gets executed again)
- Item = styled(...)`` , Item gets new function (new component)
- In JS functions are compared by reference
- The diffing algorithm compares them <Item />. The first thing it compares is the type (the component). old Item !== new Item. One function is never equal to another.
- Since it is new function (new component) It unmounts the previous Item and mounts the new one

This is why never create component inside another component. If you are forced to, then memoize the reference via `useCallback` or `useMemo`

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/code-review-avoid-declaring-react-component-inside-parent-component-1768a645f523

Comment: Can you elaborate more, please

Comment: Yeah, It makes sense just can't figure out how to do this Item in a separate file.

Comment: Move it outside of WorkoutProgress, just outside of the function in the same file. It should solve your problem.